# get the input field values from ng-repeat loop

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I hv two arrays in my controller

```
a = ['1','2','3','4','5'];
b=['2','5','1']
```

my code is this.

```
<div ng-repeat="inputs in b" >
         <div ng-repeat="m in a"  ng-if="m==inputs">
              <label for id="sk_{{inputs}}" > ID </label>

               <input type="number" placeholder="Enter "  
                         class="form-control"  
                         id="sk_{{inputs}}" min="1" 
                          ng-model="myModel.sk_{{inputs}}" 
                          ng-required="currentStep == 3" />
          </div>
    </div>


<button class="btn " ng-click="getvalues();">Next </button>
```

How can I get the input field value in one button click. (I dont need buttons for each input field.).. Please help me..

here is my plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/RCEO002i9oTWF8RmytnO?p=preview

Comment: your controller code????

Comment: In your case you will have multiple input filelds. please give some more details. Or provide a plunkr.

Comment: in my controller, $scope. a=['1','2','3','4,','5',];    $scope.b  is a dynamic array which will be the subset of $sope.a .. In this case, i will get 3 input fields.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/RCEO002i9oTWF8RmytnO?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="inputs in b" >
         <div ng-repeat="m in a"  ng-if="m==inputs">
              <label for id="sk_{{inputs}}" > ID </label>

               <input type="number" placeholder="Enter "  
                         class="form-control"  
                         id="sk_{{inputs}}" min="1" 
                          ng-model="myModel.sk[inputs]" 
                          ng-required="currentStep == 3" />
          </div>
    </div>


<button class="btn " ng-click="getvalues();">Next </button>

$scope.avail = [];

$scope.getvalues= function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.b,function(value){
        $scope.avail.push($scope.myModel.sk[value]);
    })
    alert($scope.avail);
}
```

This is what i need.. :)